# Assignment value in a session array in PHP 7.0 error

Tags: php, html, arrays, if-statement, session-cookies

I wrote this code

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    if($_POST["num"] > $_SESSION["valutazioni"][$_POST["titolo"]])
        $SESSION["valutazioni"][$_POST["titolo"] = $_POST["num"];
?>
```

The IDE gives me an error but I think my syntax is correct

Comment: use this as you forgot to close the second square bracket      `$SESSION["valutazioni"][$_POST["titolo"]] = $_POST["num"];`

Comment: missing a `]` after `$_POST["titolo"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your PHP version:
You are missing a **closing square bracket** `]`, this should be:

```
//                               here --v
$SESSION["valutazioni"][$_POST["titolo"]] = $_POST["num"];
```

Comment: Ok so what's wrong with this:
`code        <?php
        session_start();
            foreach ($SESSION["valutazioni"] as $titolo => $num) {
                echo $titolo . ": " . $num . "stelle.";
            }
        ?>`
@AymDev

Comment: @TheQwertyipad that's another question. is `$SESSION["valutazioni"]` an array ?

Comment: It is, it contains titles ("titolo") and valutations in number from 1 to 5 ("num"), do I need to initialize it?
`<?php
    session_start();
    if($_POST["num"] > $_SESSION["valutazioni"][$_POST["titolo"]])
        $SESSION["valutazioni"][$_POST["titolo"]] = $_POST["num"];
?>`

Comment: If it doesn't exists yet, you will be in trouble, yes.

Comment: Does my code under the if statement create it? @AymDev